# Installation block a determined username

Tags: inno-setup

once again I appeal to your help. More to the experts in the Inno Setup code.

I've tried several ways. But without success.

I need to block the installation of my application to users (entering in session of the operating system) with the username: EX?????

Ie. if the username is:
Ennnnnn -> OK
EXnnnnn -> No permission

(n is a number)

Can you help me. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've tried several ways. But without success.

Show us some code. What have you tried so far? Anyway..

**How to block installation, in case a certain username is used?**

In order to get the username:

- The manual lists the available constants http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts You will find `{username}` there, which is the name of the user who is running Setup or the Uninstall program.
- You can also return the username by using the `GetUserNameString()` function.
  It returns the name of the user currently logged onto the system.
  http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_getusernamestring.htm

For the comparison:

- You might work with the string functions to make sure, that a username does not start with "EX".
- The function `Pos()` might help you http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_pos.htm .
- And you could also use `Copy()`, to copy the first two chars and compare them

  - `Prefix := Copy(GetUserNameString(), 0, 2);`

Comment: 'procedure isEX(Sender:TObject; var Key: Char);
var
 s:string;
begin
 s:=('EX');
 if pos('EX',s) = 1 then begin
  Key:=#0;
  MsgBox('ERROR.', mbInformation, mb_Ok);
 end;
end;'